# Azure Functions how to add application settings to bindings

Tags: c#, azure, binding, settings, azure-functions

I'm trying to add some custom binding using my app settings for my Azure Function. I need to receive only string a string from my settings.

[image]

I would like to get simpleValue from my settings.

```
{
   "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "someValue",
      "type": "stringSetting",
      "connection": "simpleValue",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

and the get it in Run method:

```
static void GetOrders(TraceWriter log, string someValue)
{
    log.Info(someValue);
}
```

Is it even possible. Maybe there is other way to do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I already found the solution. Just add:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

and add this line to code with the key ("simpleValue") value:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["simpleValue"]
```

Comment: Would it not be `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["bindings:connection"]` instead?

Answer (score 5):

App Settings configurations can be referred in binding json as %MY_CUSTOM_CONFIG% - enclosed within percent symbols.

> Note that the ***connection*** property of triggers and bindings is a
>   special case and automatically resolves values as app settings,
>   without percent signs.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings