# Schedule a timer-triggered Azure function from the Azure Portal

Tags: azure-functions, .net-core-3.1, timer-trigger

I have an Azure Function (built in Visual Studio 2019, and running on the .NET Core 3.x stack in Azure) that is supposed to be triggered by a timer to run e.g. once per night.

I can easily create the function and define the schedule as an NCRONTAB expression like this:

```
[FunctionName("MyFunctionName")]
public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 15 3 * * 1-5")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    // Azure function code here ....
}
```

Works like a charm - **BUT** I'd like to be able to define the schedule in the Azure Portal - not in my function code - to handle e.g. DEV vs. TEST vs. PROD situations. On the DEV and TEST platforms, I might want to run this several times a day - in production maybe only once a week.

But with this approach, once the schedule is set - it's set, I cannot change it in the Azure Portal (all the input fields are grayed out / editing is disabled).

I was hoping I might be able to just skip the NCRONTAB expression in the declaration of my Azure function - like so:

```
[FunctionName("MyFunctionName")]
public void Run([TimerTrigger()]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    // Azure function code here ....
}
```

and then specify the actual CRON expression in the Azure portal - but no go, the CRON expression is mandatory....

So am I asking for too much here? Or is there a way to schedule this *outside* of my actual code base?

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51733261/1537195

Comment: @silent: thanks for the link - after a bit of trial & error, this question you've linked to provided the solution - thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the post provided by silent, we can use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]`. But I think you can refer to the solution below which is more simple.

**1.** Edit your function code in local, do not specify a cron expression in the code, use `%myTimerCron%` instead.

[image]

**2.** Publish it from local to azure, and then add a key/value in the "Application settings".
[image]

**3.** Then you can edit the cron expression by edit the value of `myTimerCron` in "Application settings" on azure portal.

By the way, when you test the code in local in visual studio, you just need to provide a cron expression with the name of "myTimerCron" in "local.setting.json".
[image]

Comment: Thanks - that seems to be doing the trick just nicely !